# Django Template: key, value not possible in for loop

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

**Error I get:**

Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 1.

Here is my **view**:

```
class Index(View):
    def get(self, request, slug):
        test = {
            1: {
                'id': 1,
                'slug': 'test-slug-1',
                'name': 'Test Name 1'
            },
            2: {
                'id': 2,
                'slug': 'test-slug-2',
                'name': 'Test Name 2'
            }
        }
        context = {
            'test': test
        }
        return render(request, 'wiki/category/index.html', context)
```

Here is my **template**:

```
{% block content %}
    <div>
        {{ test }}
        <ul>
            {% for key, value in test %}
                <li>
                    <a href="#">{{ key }}: {{ value }}</a>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I also tried the template like:

```
{% block content %}
    <div>
        {{ test }}
        <ul>
            {% for value in test %}
                <li>
                    <a href="#">{{ value }}: {{ value.name }}</a>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

No error then, but `{{ value }}` shows key (which is fine), but `{{ value.name }}` shows nothing. While `{{ test }}` shows my dict.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Loop through the dictionary's items to get the keys and values:

```
{% for key, value in test.items %}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not familiar with Django.  However, by default, Python iterates over the keys for a dictionary. I am also going to assume you are using Python2.  To get the values, you need to do:

```
{% for value in test.itervalues() %}
```

If you want both, you need to do:

```
{% for key, value in test.iteritems() %}
```

That will give you both the key and the value.

Comment: You cannot use function notation in templates, the "()" will throw an error